# Pandas groupby - set of different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'cat1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'cat2':['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z']})

  cat1 cat2
0    A    X
1    A    X
2    A    Y
3    B    Y
4    B    Y
5    C    Y
6    C    Z
7    C    Z
```

I want to group by `cat1`, and then aggregate `cat2` as sets of different values, such as

```
  cat1 cat2
0    A    (X, Y)
1    B    (Y,)
2    C    (Y, Z)
```

This is part of a bigger dataframe with more columns, each of which has its own aggregation function, so how do I pass this functionality to the aggregation dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use lambda function with `set` or `unique`, also convert output to `tuple`s:

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'cat1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
                            'cat2':['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'],
                             'col':range(8)})
print (x)
  cat1 cat2  col
0    A    X    0
1    A    X    1
2    A    Y    2
3    B    Y    3
4    B    Y    4
5    C    Y    5
6    C    Z    6
7    C    Z    7

a = x.groupby('cat1').agg({'cat2': lambda x: tuple(set(x)), 'col':'sum'})
print (a)
        cat2  col
cat1             
A     (Y, X)    3
B       (Y,)    7
C     (Y, Z)   18
```

Or:

```
a = x.groupby('cat1').agg({'cat2': lambda x: tuple(x.unique()), 'col':'sum'})
print (a)
        cat2  col
cat1             
A     (X, Y)    3
B       (Y,)    7
C     (Y, Z)   18
```

EDIT:

```
f = lambda x: tuple(x.unique())
f.__name__ = 'my_name'
a = x.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].agg(['min', 'max', 'nunique', f])
print (a)
     min max  nunique my_name
cat1                         
A      X   Y        2  (X, Y)
B      Y   Y        1    (Y,)
C      Y   Z        2  (Y, Z)
```

If there is only one `lambda` function or no problem with column name `<lambda>`:

```
a = x.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].agg(['min', 'max', 'nunique', lambda x: tuple(x.unique())])
print (a)
     min max  nunique <lambda>
cat1                          
A      X   Y        2   (X, Y)
B      Y   Y        1     (Y,)
C      Y   Z        2   (Y, Z)
```

Comment: So I already have something like 'cat2': ['min', 'max', 'nunique'], i.e. I'm already aggregating this column multiple ways. How can your solution be modified to accomodate for this? Thanks

Comment: There is possible use custom function and set name by `__name__`, check last edit.

Answer (score 3):

Groupby and unique gives you unique values

```
x.groupby('cat1').cat2.unique()

A    [X, Y]
B       [Y]
C    [Y, Z]
```

If you want to have the output in tuple, try

```
x.groupby('cat1').cat2.unique().apply(tuple)

A    (X, Y)
B      (Y,)
C    (Y, Z)
```

Comment: Please see my edits to the question above. I need to do this as part of a bigger aggregation dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

```
x.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].unique().reset_index()

# Returns 
  cat1    cat2
0    A  [X, Y]
1    B     [Y]
2    C  [Y, Z]
```

This first groups the entire dataframe by 'cat1', selects only the series 'cat2', and reduces each group to the unique set of 'cat2' values. The result puts the 'cat1' values in the index, so reset_index() will pull those values back out as a column if you need it in that format.

Comment: Please see my edits to the question above. I need to do this as part of a bigger aggregation dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
x.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].agg(lambda x: set(x))
```

**Output**

[image]

As for the simplification suggested in comments, it appears the following works at least with Python 3.6.5 and Pandas 0.23.0 (but not with Python 3.6.2 and Pandas 0.20.3) :

```
x.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].agg(set)
```

Comment: The lambda is not really necessary here, since `set` is callable. So x.groupby('cat1').agg(set) does the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't work in this case, though I thought it would too

Comment: Please see my edits to the question above. I need to do this as part of a bigger aggregation dictionary.

Comment: This solution is WAY faster than solutions based on `unique` and `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

Or we can filter the dataframe before groupby

```
x.drop_duplicates().groupby('cat1').cat2.apply(tuple)
Out[777]: 
cat1
A    (X, Y)
B      (Y,)
C    (Y, Z)
Name: cat2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please see my edits to the question above. I need to do this as part of a bigger aggregation dictionary.